# Cloudera service monitor unable to start

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera-manager

I get the following error on restarting the cloudera management service in a docker container:quickstart:latest, i had restarted after an error showed service monitor not running:

```
Mar 15, 8:45:43.760 AM  ERROR   com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.Main 
Failed to start Firehose
java.io.IOException: Unknown version of the versioned LevelDB store.
    at com.cloudera.cmon.tstore.leveldb.LDBUtils.openVersionedDB(LDBUtils.java:253)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.tstore.leveldb.LDBPartitionMetadataStore.<init>(LDBPartitionMetadataStore.java:139)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.tstore.leveldb.LDBPartitionMetadataStore.<init>(LDBPartitionMetadataStore.java:133)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.tstore.leveldb.LDBPartitionMetadataStore.createInPartitionMetadataSubdirectory(LDBPartitionMetadataStore.java:119)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.tstore.leveldb.LDBPartitionManager.createLDBPartitionManager(LDBPartitionManager.java:193)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.LDBWorkDetailsTable.<init>(LDBWorkDetailsTable.java:90)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.LDBWorkDetailsStore.<init>(LDBWorkDetailsStore.java:67)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.LDBWorkStoreFactory.createYarnWorkDetailsStore(LDBWorkStoreFactory.java:139)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.Firehose.<init>(Firehose.java:222)
    at com.cloudera.cmon.firehose.Main.main(Main.java:515)
```

Also following is shown in the cloudera.quickstart dashboard:

```
Unable to issue query: the Service Monitor is not running
```

This is a common error found in cloudera docker container booted on a single node

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing the old /var/lib/cloudera-service-monitor.